# Matching show route not generating a path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Model called `UserPrice` and when I make the show route match this:

```
match "/:id/:product_name/:purchase_date/:price", :to => "user_prices#show"
```

It generates no new route path to use nor does it change it in the view. Why doesn't it do this? How would I get it to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `as => [name]` syntax:

```
match "/:id/:product_name/:purchase_date/:price", :to => "user_prices#show", :as => :show
```

will create `show_path` and `show_url`  (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)